# Animation Error : member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this code on .m file :

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Animations
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.Button1.alpha = 1; 
                     } 
                     completion:^ (BOOL finished){}
     ];
}
```

but this line gives me error :

```
self.Button1.alpha = 1;
```

it says :

```
member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union
```

what does it means?

UPDATE : here's my .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)Button1;

@end
```

Comment: Show the declaration of `button1`.

Comment: No, that's `Button1` not `button1`.  Please show the declaration of `button1`.

Comment: sorry, typo there... but still produce same error...

Comment: lol you need to declare `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;`  Then connect it up, and that will give you a pointer to it.  Also, stick to the convention of naming actions and objects with lower-case letters at the beginning.  Upper-case should be reserved for classes/categories.

Comment: Button1 should be of UIbutton type. Here you have declared a method by name Button1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button should be a `IBOutlet` not an `IBAction`. Please correct it and update XIB references and you should be good.

e.g.

`@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;` -> link this to UIButton is XIB if you are using one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;` Then connect it from your storyboard, and that will give you a pointer to it. Also, stick to the convention of naming actions and objects with lower-case letters at the beginning. Upper-case should be reserved for classes/categories.